# 16.04 New Software Center ("Ubuntu Software") very slow or it simply doesn't work

Tags: software-center, 16.04

The new Software Center in 16.04 (Ubuntu Software, or whatever it is called) just hangs when I search for an app. Not much else to say.

Any ideas?

(I installed the old Ubuntu SOftware Center, and it works ok so far, but I would still like to know what's the problem with the new one.)

Comment: You could install Plasma Discover.  It works much faster then the Ubuntu software center.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software Center is very slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883955/ubuntu-software-center-is-very-slow)

Answer (score 6):

I am suffering the similar problem. When I want to search for an application or install updates (however it shows number of available updates), its hanging and circling there, nothing shows. A quick fix I found is:

1) kill or end the process "gnome-software" using any tool like "System monitor" or "htop" or "pkill"

2) Open the Ubuntu sofware

3) Search for the apps or install updates.

It will work like its expected, no more hanging.

Comment: For us beginners, the command to run from the terminal is `pkill gnome-software`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Ubuntu Software need to access to internet to show some relevant info (recommendations, new software, etc). I use local repositories and when connect my PC to internet, the Ubuntu Software started to work fast and now I can to install sofware from my local repository through Ubuntu Software.

Answer (score 0):

This may be somewhat off topic,but I am now using Lubuntu software center on both of my Ubuntu 16.04 machines and it works flawlessly.That being said, the current Ubuntu Software Center seems to work ok after the initial setup and update if finished on new installs.

Comment: Are you offering a reason for the _slowness in USC_ or giving a comment ?