# Ubuntu Software crashes upon loading Editor's Picks icons

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I'm experiencing the common Ubuntu Software crash. I've tried a number of solutions; none of have worked. Should I just never use this program? (This is a serious question; does it replicate certain command line functions that work more reliably?)

I'm not sure which log file to example, or where that log file would be; here's the tail of syslog after the crash:

```
May 22 23:51:22 evan-XPS-13-9350 org.gnome.Software[8435]: (gnome-software:10924): Gs-WARNING **: failed to call gs_plugin_refine_app on icons: Icon 'application-x-firmware' not present in theme (null)
May 22 23:51:22 evan-XPS-13-9350 org.gnome.Software[8435]: (gnome-software:10924): GsPlugin-WARNING **: failed to load stock icon calibre: Icon 'calibre' not present in theme (null)
May 22 23:51:23 evan-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [  681.329109] pool[10947]: segfault at ffffffffffffffb8 ip 00007f60af18eb97 sp 00007f608ed91938 error 5 in libappstream-glib.so.8.0.6[7f60af172000+42000]
```

I have tried these...

[Ubuntu Software (Software Center) Crash - Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783398/ubuntu-software-software-center-crash-ubuntu-16-04)

[16.04 New Software Center ("Ubuntu Software") very slow or it simply doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774634/16-04-new-software-center-ubuntu-software-very-slow-or-it-simply-doesnt-wor)

[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS gnome software crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857561/ubuntu-16-04-lts-gnome-software-crash)

...without any change in software behavior.

I am using 16.04 LTS on a Dell XPS13, configured to dual boot Ubuntu and Win10.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with your issue, but `synaptic` is probably what most people use as an alternative, though I prefer `aptitude` (which is terminal/curses based).  Both need installation (`sudo apt install..`) before use.  Neither provide pretty pictures like Ubuntu Software, nor have ratings.. but are faster  (I'd suggest trying `synaptic`)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, I installed Software Center as an alternative:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue, it looks like somtething is wrong with libappstream.
I managed to find a workaround:

```
gnome-software --prefer-local
```

**edit:** works in general but still crashes when loading some categories